# Is this implied function unique?

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $f(p)>0$ be a function for $p\in(0,1)$ such that $$ f(p_{1}\times p_{2})=f(p_{1})\times f(p_{2})$$ for all $p_{1},p_{2}\in (0,1)$. Does $f(p)$ have to be of the form $f(p)=p^{\alpha}$ for some fixed $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample or, rather, an idea how to construct one (I did not check all details).Take $a_0=1/2$. Let $f(a_0^\alpha)=a_0^\alpha$ for every rational number $\alpha>0$. Note that the set $S_0$ of all positive rational powers of $1/2$ is a multiplicative subsemigroup of $(0,1)$. Suppose we already defined $f$ on some multiplicative semigroup $S$ of $(0,1)$. We say that such a subsemigroup $S$ is **group-like**  if for every $x,y\in S$ and $x^\alpha/y\in (0,1)$ for some rational $\alpha>0$, we have $x^\alpha/y\in S$. Clearly, $S_0$ is group-like. Suppose we have already defined $f$ on some group-like subsemigroup $S$ of $(0,1)$, and $x\in (0,1)\setminus S$. Consider any element $z$ of $(0,1)\setminus S$ and let $S'$ be the smallest group-like subsemigroup of $(0,1)$ containing $S,x$. Then we can define $f(x)=x^2$ and extend $f$ to the whole $S'$. By Zorn lemma, we can extend $f$ to the whole $(0,1)$. That $f(p)$ is not of the form $p^\alpha$ for any $\alpha$.

Comment: I don't follow your statement yet - maybe it come to me later. Your function, if it exists, must be a non-differentiable one since I have figured out the answer to the differentiable functions $f$ is YES.

Comment: It is not even continuous. The construction even uses the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Is the function strictly monotone?

Comment: No, $f(1/2)=1/2. f(\sqrt{1/3}=1/3$, so it is not increasing. It is also easy to see that it is not decreasing, because $f(\frac1{\sqrt[4]{3}})=\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks, I get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Observe that:

$$f(p^2)=f(p\times p)=f(p)\times f(p)=f^2(p)$$ and proceed on induction to see that:

$$f(p^{k+1})=f(p^k\times p)=f(p^k)\times f(p)=f^k(p)\times f(p)=f^{k+1}(p)$$

This general result $f(p^n)\equiv (f(p))^n$ implies that $f(p)$ is monomial.

To show this, suppose $f$ has $k$ terms, then $f^n$ has $k^n$ terms by the multinomial theorem, so $k=k^n\implies k=1$.

Of the monomial forms, only the exponential $p^\alpha$ has the desired multiplicativity property.

Comment: " suppose $f$ has $k$ terms" What does it mean?

Comment: That $$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^k f_j(x)$$ where each $f_j$ is monomial. For example, $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ has two terms. Observe that $f^2(x)=g^2+gh+gh+h^2$ has four ($=2^2$) terms when non-simplified, but still has three after simplification. Therefore the statement $$f^2(x)\equiv f(x^2)$$ is totally impossible from the get go because the number of terms don't match up.

Comment: How many terms does $\exp(x)$ have? What about non-continuous functions?

Comment: $\exp(x)$ is a monomial, whose square is therefore also monomial, but doesn't satisfy the question. On the other hand, the Maclaurin series of $e^x$ (which is equal to $e^x$, but a distinct concept) is an infinite series. But, if one were to denote the nth approximation by said series as $M_n$, it is obvious at a glance that $M_n^2$ has more terms than $M_n$. In the case of  discontinuous functions, I don't see why they make a difference to my argument. E.g. $(x^{-1}+\tan(x))^2=x^{-2}+2x^{-1}\tan(x)+\tan^2(x)$

Comment: I am not sure you know what a function is.

Comment: I do, and I intentionally didn't say that the infinite series wasn't a function, because it is. However, perhaps I should clarify that, as I thought was obvious, my definition of a "$k$-termed function", only makes sense for a finite $k\in\Bbb N$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109343/discussion-between-jcaa-and-rhys-hughes).